# Get Win 32 window from Wnd Proc call

Tags: c#, wpf, hwnd, winforms-interop

In my wpf project, i am hosting a win 32 window with listbox control. In this, is it possible to get that Win 32 window in Message Hook event handler?

```
var view = new Win32Host(source.Handle, mViewMgr);
view.MessageHook += View_MessageHook;
IntPtr View_MessageHook(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
{
    handled = false;
}
```

Any one please provide your suggestion to me?

Comment: What's the first parameter of View_MessageHook?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what **Win32Host** is but if you have an **HWND** you may be able to get some associated object. It really depends on the class. So for example if the HWND is for a Windows Forms control then you can use the [System.Windows.Forms.Control.FromHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.fromhandle.aspx) or [FromChildHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.fromchildhandle.aspx) method. If the HWND was the window hosting WPF content then you would use [HwndSource.FromHwnd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.hwndsource.fromhwnd.aspx) and get the [RootVisual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.hwndsource.rootvisual.aspx) from that to get the root element (e.g. a WPF Window or the root element of a Popup).

Comment: Andrew-Here Win32Host is a HWND Host and i host that Win32Host as child to my wpf control. Here i want that Win32Host in MessageHook event.

Comment: Then no there is no automatic way to do that. Why not just keep a Dictionary<IntPtr, WeakReference> where the key is the Hwnd and the value is a weak reference to the Win32Host? If Win32Host is your own derived HwndHost then you could have it do that storage. Or perhaps more simply create a class that stores a reference to the Win32Host and it hooks the MessageHook event.